# Share color values and other read-only values across multiple QML files

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm looking for a simple way to share read-only values across multiple QML files, for instance; lets say I have a label element:

```
        Label {
            id: titleLabel
            text: listView.currentItem ? listView.currentItem.text : "IDEAL Networks"
            font.pixelSize: 20
            elide: Label.ElideRight
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: red;
            padding: {
                left: 14
            }
        }
```

The `color` and `padding` values need to be used in other QML files and other areas of the same file.

Rather than re-typing `red` and 14 in multiple locations is there a way I can create a shared library containing these values instead to make it easier to update globally at a later date?

*** Update ***

I've followed the instructions here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

However when I import the custom `CustomStyles 1.0` module I get an error - module "CustomStyles" is not installed.

```
//Style.qml with custom singleton type definition
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property int textSize: 20
    property color textColor: "green"
}

// qmldir declaring the singleton type
module CustomStyles
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml

// singleton type in use
import QtQuick 2.0
import CustomStyles 1.0

Text {
    font.pixelSize: Style.textSize
    color: Style.textColor
    text: "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: Your question is interpreted in many ways, you could give a real context, for example I can think of a singleton, and also create a custom item, maybe a repeater, or a personalized style, etc.

Comment: I think a singleton would serve me best, its just not clear how I declare on, import it and then reference it from the docs I have found. @eyllanesc - I likely use this more specifically for colours, a place to store gradient and color fill values so I can easily change them later.

Comment: Read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html, there is a clear and complete example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use a singleton, in your case you must import it correctly, assuming that the .qml are in the same qrc you just have to do the following:

**.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        [...]
        <file>style/qmldir</file>
        <file>style/style.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**Style.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
   readonly  property int padding: 20
   readonly property color textColor: "green"
}
```

**qmldir**

```
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "style"

Text {
    font.pixelSize: Style.textSize
    color: Style.textColor
    text: "Hello World"
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48889600) there is an example

Comment: What if the files exist in a sub-directory:

...
        <file>style/style.qml</file>
        <file>style/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>

Comment: I saw, I had to modify import "style" to import "../style"

Comment: @CLiown surely to .qml is inside another folder

Comment: Yes it is, I have a /pages directory with my screens in.

Answer (score 1):

If your object tree is not too deep, it is applicable to simply declare the properties in the root object of `main.qml`, which will make them resolvable from all qml files thanks to dynamic scoping, as long as you take care not to shadow them by identically named local properties.

If your tree is deep it will be more efficient to use a singleton, which will cut down the lookup time.

You can also chose a closer tree node, it doesn't have to be the root element, it just has to be deep enough so that all objects that need to access it are nested in it, and the properties have to be declared in the root element of the particular qml file in order to get dynamic scoping.

Comment: curious: _if your tree is deep it will be more efficient  ..._, is that _lookup time_ important at runtime? does properties  aliases solve this ?

Comment: For me it takes several hundred of objects nested dozens of levels deep before it becomes noticeable, and even more until it becomes problematic.  Most qml apps are much smaller and shallower than that. I haven't tested aliases, but keep in mind they are not free, they incur runtime cost too. Unlike C++ where references have zero cost since it is all compiled ahead of time and dynamic, every reference in qml is being looked up, hence the performance recommendation to cache even local property values when using them in tight loops in a `var` rather than directly addressing.